# my code doesn't work! How to convert a string to a list command?

Tags: python-3.x

I have already tried as below.

```
key_list = ["list_of_spin_time", "list_of_temperature", "list_of_exchange_rate"]

variances = {}

for i in range(len(key_list)):
    variances[key_list[i]]=variance(key_list[i])

print(variances)
```

Comment: Please read what the error says. It should clarify it for you. This question does not belong on SO.

Comment: Are you trying to get a dictionary with unique values ? Please specify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you only copied a portion of your code here, so it gives an error saying "name 'variance' is not defined".

From what I guess is that in your code each string in `key_list` corresponds to a list, and you want to have a dictionary `variances` with keys as the strings in `key_list` and values as the lists each string points to.

If I guess it right then the following should resolve your problem.

```
list_of_spin_time = [1,2,3]
list_of_temperature = [70,80,90]
list_of_exchange_rate = [0.8,0.9,1.0]

key_list = ["list_of_spin_time", "list_of_temperature", "list_of_exchange_rate"]

variances = {}

for i in range(len(key_list)):
    variances[key_list[i]]=eval(key_list[i])  # apply your variance function here

print(variances)
## {'list_of_spin_time': [1, 2, 3], 'list_of_temperature': [70, 80, 90], 'list_of_exchange_rate': [0.8, 0.9, 1.0]}
```

Hope this helps.